# Difference between nodupkey in SAS and SELECT * DISTINCT FROM table_name in SQL

Tags: sql, hive, sas, duplicates

I have a data set with 2 fields storing Strings. 
1.In SAS when I do a nodupkey on the dataset I get ~200 records. 
2.In SQL when I do a SELECT DISTINCT / GROUP BY/ PARTITION BY I am getting ~2000 records. This SQL code is run on HIVE which is hosted on an AWS EMR server.

The data set I am working on has NULL in some of the records for on of the fields. I am not doing anything else apart from what I mentioned in point 1 and 2.

I am looking for explanation as to why there is a huge mismatch between these 2 when I am doing just a simple duplicate removal.

Comment: It would be a lot easier to understand and answer your question with a sample data. The two methods you mentioned process data differently.

Comment: A proper question will show the SQL code and the SORT code, describe the table layouts (columns), and variations tried (such as keeping or selecting only the key columns) –

Comment: You have to show your code for us to provide a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

Distinct operates on all fields in select statement and the database will likely consider nulls and blanks as different. 
SAS does not consider nulls and blanks as different and only filters based on the variables listed in the BY statement.